# How do I get Unread/Unseen Notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getstream-io

Hi I have been able to implement Notification Feed fine but I would like to get a count of number of unseen or unread activities in notification feed. How do i do this on Stream Rails or Stream Ruby? The documentation says "The notification feed also includes the count of unseen and unread activities." but i don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`StreamRails.feed_manager.get_notification_feed(ID).get()['unread']`